# XDocument Append would produce incorrectly structured document

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following code:

```
private static XNode CreateXmlFolderSchema()
{
    XDocument document = new XDocument(new XElement("configurations"));
    document.Root!.Add(new XElement("config", new XAttribute("name", "RootFolder")));
    return document.FirstNode!;
}
```

which produces the following XML:

```
<configurations>
  <config name="RootFolder" />
</configurations>
```

I also have

```
private static XNode MapFolderToXmlDocument(Folder rootFolder, XNode parentNode)
{
    XElement folder = new XElement("folder",
    new XAttribute("name", rootFolder.Name),
    new XAttribute("root", rootFolder.Root),
    new XAttribute("default", rootFolder.Default),
    new XAttribute("permission", rootFolder.Permission),
    new XAttribute("expiry", rootFolder.Expiry),
    CreateActionElement(rootFolder));
    parentNode.AddAfterSelf(folder);
    return folder;
}
```

Which produces the following XML:

```
<folder name="/"
        root="false"
        default="false"
        permission="read, write"
        expiry="0">
    <action bUploadChangePermssions="false"
            eUploadNewPermissions=""
            sUploadRename=""
            bUploadSubmit="false"
            sUploadDelete=""
            eDownloadIndicator=""
            sDownloadIndicator=""
            sDownloadWriteEvent="false"
            bChangePermissions="false"
            eDownloadNewPermissions=""
            bUploadSessionEnd="false"
            bDeleteOnDownload="false" />
</folder>
```

What I want to achieve:

```
<configurations>
    <config name="RootFolder" />
    <folder name="/"
        root="false"
        default="false"
        permission="read, write"
        expiry="0">
    <action bUploadChangePermssions="false"
            eUploadNewPermissions=""
            sUploadRename=""
            bUploadSubmit="false"
            sUploadDelete=""
            eDownloadIndicator=""
            sDownloadIndicator=""
            sDownloadWriteEvent="false"
            bChangePermissions="false"
            eDownloadNewPermissions=""
            bUploadSessionEnd="false"
            bDeleteOnDownload="false" />
    </folder>
</configurations>
```

According to various XML validators online, it's valid xml, however when performing the following:

```
MapFolderToXmlDocument(someFolderObject, CreateXmlFolderSchema());
```

I get `InvalidOperationException`"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document." on `parentNode.AddAfterSelf(folder);` inside of `MapFolderToXmlDocument`

Comment: You forgot to show what MapToXmlSftpFolder is.

Comment: @Crowcoder Ah, I forgot to rename that method. Updated the post. Hopefully, that makes it clearer.

Comment: Change :  return document.FirstNode!; to  return document.Root;  Then change parentNode.AddAfterSelf(folder); to parentNode.Add(folder);  The issue is the second change.  AddAfterSelf is adding a sibling to root instead of adding a child to root.